# Problem with runtime because of double for loop

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, runtime, ode

I created an array for some differential equations (deSolve) and want to put the values for several subjects (n=250) with a variable (n=1000) in an array, but now I'm using two for loops and it takes way to much runtime. I don't know how to improve my code. Any suggestions?

```
array.fruit <- array(NA, dim=c(X+1, length(yini)+1, 250, 1000), 
dimnames = list(NULL, c("time","Glycogen", "FatMass", "LeanMass", "ECF", "BW", "ATh", "BMI"))) #here I created an empty array
for (o in 1:250){
    for (i in 1:1000){  
        array.fruit[,,o,i] <- ode(func=model.fruit, y=yini, parms=pars, times=times1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide `X` and `yini` and all other missing variables

Comment: X = 1825 (time) and  yini <- c(Glycogen=glyc.init[o], FatMass=FatMass.init[o], LeanMass=LeanMass.init[o], ECF=ECF.init[o], BW=BW.init5[o], ATh=ATh.init, BMI=Doet.fruit$BMI2[o])

Comment: I don't understand the need for the loops since 'o' and 'i' are not used in the `ode` function.

Comment: Will this call result to constant value? ode(func=model.fruit, y=yini, parms=pars, times=times1) if so have a variable and assigned with that outside of the loop. Then in the loop itself, assigned that new variable to array element